# Problems with unnested models inside nested controllers rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the following model `view`. And the following controller `Admin::ViewsController` with the following code:

```
class Admin::ViewsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_admin_view, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    # GET /admin/views
    # GET /admin/views.json
    def index
        @views = View.all
    end

    # GET /admin/views/1
    # GET /admin/views/1.json
    def show
        filter_requests = FilterRequests.new(params)
        @requests = filter_requests.determine_what_to_do
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js           
            format.html
        end
    end

    # GET /admin/views/new
    def new
        @view = View.new
    end

    # GET /admin/views/1/edit
    def edit
    end

    # POST /admin/views
    # POST /admin/views.json
    def create
        @view = View.new(admin_view_params)

        respond_to do |format|
            if @view.save
                format.html { redirect_to @view, notice: 'View was successfully created.' }
                format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @view }
            else
                format.html { render action: 'new' }
                format.json { render json: @view.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    # PATCH/PUT /admin/views/1
    # PATCH/PUT /admin/views/1.json
    def update
        respond_to do |format|
            if @view.update(admin_view_params)
                format.html { redirect_to @view, notice: 'View was successfully updated.' }
                format.json { head :no_content }
            else
                format.html { render action: 'edit' }
                format.json { render json: @view.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    # DELETE /admin/views/1
    # DELETE /admin/views/1.json
    def destroy
        @view.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to admin_views_url }
            format.json { head :no_content }
        end
    end

    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_admin_view
        @view = View.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def admin_view_params
        params[:admin_view]
    end
end
```

`uninitialized constant Admin::ViewsController::View` is the error I am getting at `set_admin_view` code. This is the following routes:

```
namespace :admin do
    scope :requests do
         resources :views
    end
end
```

Why am I getting this problem?

Comment: What is the path of your `views_controller.rb` file?

Comment: And also what is the path of your `View` model file?

Comment: `views_controller.rb` is inside `controllers/admin/views_controller.rb` and model file is at `models/view.rb`

Comment: I guess your model file should be in `models/admin` folder.Try creating an `admin` folder  and put the `model` View in it.

Comment: I'd expect the View class to be available if it's defined in the normal models folder.  I have to ask - is the View class definitely defined inside the view.rb file?

Comment: @Pavan I don't want the View model to be namespaced.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I don't understand what you are asking me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your view model isnt namespaced try

```
@view = ::View.find(params[:id])
```